# How can I remove text above the header?

Tags: debug

[image: Text above the header]

Embarassing problem here. A while back I added a debugging statement of showing the url of the current page, but now I can't find it to remove it. I don't remember what methods/variables I used either. I have checked header.php and footer.php, but it doesn't seem to be there. None of my child theme files extend these either. I want to remove this statment asap. Let the downvotes commence.

Comment: judging by the url format, it looks like get_home_path() may be at play here, but I still cannot find it.

Comment: Maybe using 'inspect element' of your browser and find the div tag it uses, a good editor and do a search for that div, probably just a 1 minute job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be output a ton of different places and ways, but judging on what you
re saying, and that you can't see anything in your header.php, check your theme `functions.php`.

Look for something along the lines of this:

`dirname(__FILE__);`

`pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

`SCRIPT_FILENAME`

If no luck still, check `index.php` and then check mu-plugins folder for files.

Comment: *whew* thx Bryan. 
I was hooking into wp_head with: 
global $template;
  print_r( $template );

I just needed to remove this from functions.php and things went right as rain.